# Get the field value with a Cursor

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm creating an application and I have problems with `Cursor`. I have an `SQLiteDatabase` that returns me a `Cursor` when I try to fetch the values with this function:

```
public Cursor fetchOption(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
        KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
        null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```

I don't know how to obtain the value of the field in the `Cursor`. If I do that like so:

```
String a = mOptionDb.fetchOption(0).getColumnName(0).toString();
String b = mOptionDb.fetchOption(0).getColumnName(1).toString();
String c = mOptionDb.fetchOption(0).getColumnName(2).toString();
```

I only obtain the name of the columns (`_id, title, body`) but not the values. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I think you can forget about checking for null.

Instead check if there is data and then access the columns using the cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = fetchOption(0);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) // data?
   System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")); 

cursor.close(); // that's important too, otherwise you're gonna leak cursors
```

It might also make sense to read an Android tutorial. The notepad tutorial seems to fit the bill: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now it works. I forget every access to close the cursor...

Comment: every time I have this problem, I come back here and realize that I forgot cursor.moveToFirst(). thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `Cursor`'s `get*` methods to retrieve values from the result:

```
long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
long title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
...
```

Better practice is obviously to use constants (often provided by ContentProviders) instead of calls to `getColumnIndex` with hardcoded strings.

Comment: with the part :
int a = mOptionDb.fetchOption(0).getColumnIndex("title");
I obtain "1". 
But with mOptionDb.fetchOption(0).getString(a);
I obtain errors :
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(628): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(628): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
It's like there isn't datas?!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this mechanism.

```
Cursor record=db.test(finalDate);     
if(record.getCount()!=0){
    if(record.moveToFirst()){
        do{               
            Imgid1=record.getString(record.getColumnIndex(Database.PHOTO));                
        }while(record.moveToNext());                          
    } 
    record.close();        
}
```