# How to retrieve data from cursor class

Tags: android

I need to know how to retrieve data from cursor. I need this because the ringtonemanager returns all the audio files in form of cursor object, I need to know how to retrieve the values.

Anbudan.

Comment: Just read the documentation in the API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html Or there is a nice tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html Also this question could maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903343/cursor-get-the-field-value-android

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Once you have the Cursor object, you can do something like this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   do{
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
      // do what ever you want here
   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: There is a ")" missing here: String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data")); . Not serious, just to complete your answer.

Comment: Am I right in the sense that even if you are only expecting one row, you need to call cursor.moveToFirst() as else the array containing the data will always be empty???

Comment: I thing "!cursor.isAfterLast()" should stay in your while loop, as "Some Noob Student", otherwise it will cause ad infinite loop.

Comment: This code will crash trying to call `getString(int)` on a row after the cursor's last row. Look at @tcb answer for a solution that actually works

Comment: What's with the "data" here? Is it specific to the question asked?

Answer (score 22):

This looks a bit better:

```
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Salvador's answer will continue to fetch data from the row after the last row because `moveToNext()` will only return false when the cursor is pointing at the row after the last row. It will continue to iterate even if the cursor is pointing at the last row.

The correct template should be:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
      // do what ever you want here
      cursor.moveToNext();
   }
}
cursor.close();
```