# my sqlite cursor returns empty result for a query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a small function for checking to see if a records already exists in my sqlite database. There is data in the database that should match the query, i have verified this by opening up the database.But i get an empty result.

Below is the function, it takes in a parameter and uses that as the search parameter. i have also verified that the parameter is correct.

```
public boolean checkParent(String email)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = null;

    try
    {
        res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM parents WHERE email = ' " + email + " ' ",null);
        res.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Error checking parent", ex.toString());
    }

    if(res == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the spaces arond before and after `email` or even better used Pepared statements. No email in your DB starts and ends with a space I guess

Comment: use `SELECT * FROM parents WHERE email = ?` and pass `saelectionArgs` to `rawQuery` method

Comment: You are closing cursor and then accessing the cursor. will it work?

Answer (score 1):

Right way to pass argument in **rawQuery** method.

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM parents WHERE email = ?",new String[]{email});
```

Comment: i still get android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@2a39dbba as the result of the query

Comment: How to read data from cursor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810615/how-to-retrieve-data-from-cursor-class

Check this answer it will help.

Comment: I am tried your answer ,still the same issue .The cursor return as empty .

Answer (score 1):

You are checking whether the cursor object `res` is null. This will never happen; `rawQuery()` *always* returns a cursor object.

You have to check whether the cursor is empty, i.e., whether the cursor actually contains any rows. To do this, call a method like `moveToFirst()` and check if it succeeds.

Or even better, use a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) that does handle the cursor for you:

```java
public boolean checkParent(String email)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,
            "parents", "email = ?", new String[]{ email });
    return count > 0;
}
```