# How to output SQLite column to ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I have an SQLite Database.

Here's some of the code setting it up:

```
// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION};

// Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_DESCRIPTION = 2;

// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbMetrics";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainMetrics";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT"
                + ");";
```

I want to output one of my columns `KEY_NAME` as an ArrayList.

To do this, I have so far generated the following code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllStringValues() {
        ArrayList<String> myStringValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor result = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
                new String[] {KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null,
                null, null);

            **********CODE NEEDED HERE***********
        

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myStringValues.toArray()));
        return myStringValues ;

    }
```

However, I am not sure how I get the data from the column into an ArrayList from here.

## My Question

Can someone give me some assistance as to how to design a loop that will go through each row in the column and put that data in an ArrayList?

I'm pretty sure I will need to at some point use

`result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME))`

in order to do this, but again, I'm not sure how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the documentation for the Cursor class? There are a few methods that stick out to iterate it

Comment: Start with this, then learn how to extract data out of the Cursor.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810615/how-to-retrieve-data-from-cursor-class

Comment: The problem is, the answers provided here seem to result in only unique values being printed. Like for instance, I want my output to print `[Test,Test2,Test2,Test]` but instead it removes duplicates and prints `[Test,Test2]`. How can this be avoided? I want it to print everything, not merely distinct ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (Cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    keyname.add(Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex("keyname")));
                    key_description.add(Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex("key_description")));

                } while (Cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            Cursor.close();
```

try this code if doesnt work, tell me

Comment: Here's the problem: it works, but some of the entries have the same value. Like for instance, it should print `[Test,Test2,Test2,Test]` but instead it removes duplicates and prints `[Test,Test2]`. How can this be avoided? I want it to print everything, not merely distinct ones.

Comment: no it will not remove duplicates, arraylist can hold duplicate enteries. I have tried this code and it works fine.

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: can you print these arraylist in logcat and show to me..  as well as print all table in logcat. Then we can see whats going wrong in your case.

Comment: I resolved it. Amazingly, the word "true" in the `db.query` part was the problem and was removing all the non-distinct entries. No idea why. I just did a series of debugging steps and figured it out after several hours.

Comment: I have a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906892/how-can-i-use-viewbinder-to-connect-switches-to-my-sqlite-database if you have a chance to offer ur words of wisdom it would be appreciated :)