# Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range. The statement has 0 parameters

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

How do i fix this error?
I am using SQLite to store my data and I have my CursorAdapter.java and DBHelper class and I am trying to use everything on the MainActivity,here is the code for the MainActivity.java

```
  ArrayList<ItemsHolder> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mydb.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("select * from Todo", new String[]{COLUMN_ID});
    while(res.moveToNext()) {
        ItemsHolder itemsHolder = new ItemsHolder();
        itemsHolder.item = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ITEM_NAME));
        array_list.add(itemsHolder);
    }
        TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, res);
        // Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

But I keep getting the error mentioned above, what does it even mean?please help

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810615/how-to-retrieve-data-from-cursor-class . Try both the first and the second answer.

Comment: I tried both, im still getting the same exception

Comment: Are you sure that your variable `res` has the value and content you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL (`"select * from Todo"`) doesn't match the number of parameters you are passing to it (`new String[]{COLUMN_ID}`).  If you are passing arguments to db.rawQuery, you must have placeholders in the SQL you are running.  For example, something like:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE column_id = ?", new String[]{COLUMN_ID});
```

The error you are getting is because you are passing in a parameter to the query (`COLUMN_ID`), but there are no parameters (question marks) to bind the value to.

Comment: Hey @Metroids I did that and now I am getting this exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist