# How do i extract content from a listview and store it as a string?

Tags: android, string, listview, sms

My app reads the messages from the phone's inbox and displays it on a list view in the app. I am trying to extract the message's content itself and store it as a string for future intent use. How do i go about this? When i check log cat it tells me that my content in the list view is not even a string in the first place so i cant extract it just yet. Do i need to convert the content to string first? if yes, how can i do this?

This is my current codes, how i extracted and displayed the messages from the inbox to the app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    //  GUI Widget
    Button getSmsButton, viewGoogleMapButton;
    TextView lblMsg, lblNumber;
    ListView messageListView;
    Context ctx = this;
    String msg;

    // Cursor Adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init GUI Widget
        getSmsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getSmsButton);
        getSmsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        messageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);

        viewGoogleMapButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewGoogleMapButton);
        viewGoogleMapButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent startGoogleMap = new Intent(ctx, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(startGoogleMap);
            }
        });
     }    

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (v != getSmsButton) 
             return;

         // Create Inbox box URI
         Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

         // List required columns
         String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};

         // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
         ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

         // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
         Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

         // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
         adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                    new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
                    R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber});
         messageListView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
}
```

I tried putting these codes to extract the content and store as string but it does not work

```
messageListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String data=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Log.i("msg", data);
    }});
}
```

this is my row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lblMsg"></TextView>

<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00f"
    android:id="@+id/lblNumber"></TextView>
```

Comment: Did you try parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()?

Comment: yesss its part of my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the text of selected item fro your ListView as follows

```
    messageListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //for getting the position
            String data=messageListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    //for getting the text from selected item
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg); //textView in your listView 
                    String text = textView.getText().toString();
            Log.i("msg", "Selected item: " + text + " - " + position,);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you have Cursor object, you can retrieve data from it. Please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810615/how-to-retrieve-data-from-cursor-class)