# Why do i get android.database.sqlite.sqlitecursor @ error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I get null value whenever I try to display the value of nexpdate. I get the following error android.database.sqlite.sqlitecursor @ .

```
  // insertion of values in renew table
public void insertrenew (String rcode, String nexpdate) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("rcode", rcode);
            contentValues.put("nexpdate", nexpdate);
            db.insert("renew", null, contentValues);
        }

//java code to get the value of nexpdate 
public String  getrenew (String rcode) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT nexpdate from renew where rcode = " + rcode;
            String cursor = String.valueOf(db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null));
            return cursor;

        }
```

Comment: Can you share exact error that you are getting? Check the logcat output and share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting an error:

```
android.database.sqlite.sqlitecursor @ XXXX // where XXXX indicates object code
```

### Reason/Details:

Reason being here is you are directly casting `Cursor` object into the `String` and that's where an issue is!

`String cursor = String.valueOf(db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null));`

FYI, `rawQuery()` method actually returns `Cursor` value and we need to iterate through the cursor actually to get the needed data. You may refer [How to retrieve data from cursor class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810615/how-to-retrieve-data-from-cursor-class) for more details on getting data from the Cursor.