# Android: Retrieve contact name from phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number, contactscontract

I would like to retrieve the name of a contact associated with an incoming telephone number. As I process the incoming number in the broascastreceiver having a String with the name of the incoming caller would help my project greatly.

I would think this involves a query using the sql WHERE clause as a filter, but do I need to sort the contacts? An example or hint would be of great assistance.

Comment: For the facility of others, I have written a post which contains the whole code to query name, photo, contact ID, etc. with decent explanation. The code contains snippets as found on different answers, but more organized and tested. Link: http://hellafun.weebly.com/home/get-information-of-a-contact-from-number

Answer (score 83, accepted):

For that you need to use the optimized PhoneLookup provider as described.

Add the permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Then:

```
public String getContactName(final String phoneNumber, Context context)
{
    Uri uri=Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};

    String contactName="";
    Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName=cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}
```

Comment: Right off the dev page, thank you for the quick response. The toString() method in Uri should convert this query to the contacts name?

Comment: No, it won't you will have to resolve the Cursor yourself. For some help check this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903343/cursor-get-the-field-value-android

Comment: I would initialize a cursor with a managedQuery using the URI, then move the cursor to the fist position and get the data? Once I get the cursor at the first position I use getString? I assume that the first position would be right because the query is for a number therefore the query will pull up names only for that number?

Comment: That's exactly how you have to do. Don't forget to wrap in a try/catch.

Comment: What specifically goes into the rest of that query? This answer isn't much more helpful than the already existing documentation.

Comment: You should answer with full code. After query how to iterate and get name. Beginner can not understand this 2 lines. You should make function that returns name based on number

Comment: Hello, I tried something similar, but it didn't work. Here is my question, I would really appreciate your help! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097844/get-contact-name/35098111#35098111

Comment: This throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column display_name`. @Vikram.exe's answer is better.

Answer (score 90):

Although this has already been answered, but here is the complete function to get the contact name from number. Hope it will help others:

```
public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}
```

[**Updating** based on Marcus's comment]

You will have to ask for this permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`

Comment: it makes the app "not responsible" when resuming the activity. How should I do that

Comment: I'm also getting ANR every time I run on Android 5.1

Comment: Probably for the ANR you need to run it on a thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: Worth to mention is that this needs the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>` permission

Comment: Hello, I tried something similar, but it didn't work. Here is my question, I would really appreciate your help! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097844/get-contact-name/35098111#35098111

Answer (score 26):

This was very helpful, here's my final code for retrieving the caller's Name, id, and Photo:

```
private void uploadContactPhoto(Context context, String number) {

Log.v("ffnet", "Started uploadcontactphoto...");

String name = null;
String contactId = null;
InputStream input = null;

// define the columns I want the query to return
String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};

// encode the phone number and build the filter URI
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

// query time
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    // Get values from contacts database:
    contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
    name =      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

    // Get photo of contactId as input stream:
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contactId));
    input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), uri);

    Log.v("ffnet", "Started uploadcontactphoto: Contact Found @ " + number);            
    Log.v("ffnet", "Started uploadcontactphoto: Contact name  = " + name);
    Log.v("ffnet", "Started uploadcontactphoto: Contact id    = " + contactId);

} else {

    Log.v("ffnet", "Started uploadcontactphoto: Contact Not Found @ " + number);
    return; // contact not found

}

// Only continue if we found a valid contact photo:
if (input == null) {
    Log.v("ffnet", "Started uploadcontactphoto: No photo found, id = " + contactId + " name = " + name);
    return; // no photo
} else {
    this.type = contactId;
    Log.v("ffnet", "Started uploadcontactphoto: Photo found, id = " + contactId + " name = " + name);
}
```

... then just do whatever you want with "input" (their photo as an InputStream), "name", and "contactId".

And here are the docs listing the ~15 or so columns you have access to, just add them to the projection near the start of the code up above:
        http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html

Answer (score 2):

This version is the same as Vikram.exe's answer with code to avoid the ANR

```
interface GetContactNameListener {
    void contactName(String name);
}

public void getContactName(final String phoneNumber,final GetContactNameListener listener) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                return;
            }
            String contactName = null;
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }

            if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }

            listener.contactName(contactName);
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the contact number from which you are getting the call in the following method. This Method will check whether the contact is saved in your mobile or  not. If the contact is saved then it will return the contact name otherwise it return a string unknown number

Add this code in your Broadcast receiver class

```
    public String getContactDisplayNameByNumber(String number,Context context) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    name = "Incoming call from";

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    try {
        if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
            contactLookup.moveToNext();
            name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            // this.id =
            // contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID));
            // String contactId =
            // contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
        }else{
            name = "Unknown number";
        }
    } finally {
        if (contactLookup != null) {
            contactLookup.close();
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

to get Source code visit [this link](https://github.com/VinodDirishala/AndroidApplicationDevelopment/blob/master/Caller.zip)

Answer (score 0):

For that, we can use the  `PhoneLookup` provider to get the names or contact details using the mobile number.

Add the permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Add the following custom kotlin method in your activity and call the same with the required mobile number.

```
fun getContactNameByPhoneNumber(context: Context, phoneNumber: String): String? {
        var phone = phoneNumber
        if(phoneNumber != null && phoneNumber.length > 0 && phoneNumber[0].equals('+'))
            phone = phoneNumber.substring(3)

        val projection = arrayOf(
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
        )
        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, null, null
        ) ?: return ""
        for (i in 0 until cursor.count) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i)
            val nameFieldColumnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val phoneFieldColumnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)

            if(phone.equals(cursor.getString(phoneFieldColumnIndex)))
                return cursor.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex)
        }
        return "Unknown"
    }
```

For more: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names