# How can I query Android contact based on a phone number?

Tags: android

How can I query Android contact (in android 2.1) based on a phone number?

I used to use People.CONTENT_URI (before android 2.1) but that is now deprecated.

Thank you.

Comment: More good examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079365/android-retrieve-contact-name-from-phone-number/8695649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way to lookup a contact using just the phone number. This is how the caller ID does it.

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
    PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
managedQuery(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,...
```

Comment: Where can I find code? I would like to know what is the '...' in the above code?

Thank you.

Comment: That's just an example.

managedQuery(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null, null);

would only return the display name.