# Match number to contact in android app

Tags: java, android, contacts

Have an android app that prints with a toast pop up, and reads out a received message with tts.  I use "String origin = smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress();" to get the phone number of the sender.
I want to query the contacts list on the phone, so if the received number matches any contacts, it will print & read out the name of the sender instead.  Otherwise, if the number is not recognised, it will default back to just printing & reading the OriginatingAddress number.
Iv'e looked at [How can I query Android contact based on a phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206276/how-can-i-query-android-contact-based-on-a-phone-number) - but not quite sure howto go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(origin));
Cursor phonesCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(phoneUri, new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

if(phonesCursor != null && phonesCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    displayName = phonesCursor.getString(0); // this is the contact name
}//end if
```

Go this eventually.

Answer (score -1):

That question had the answer and posted the code.

```
Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                            Uri.encode(mNumber));
Cursor phonesCursor = managedQuery(phoneUri, new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
if(phonesCursor != null && phonesCursor.moveToFirst()) {
     String displayName = phonesCursor.getString(0); // this is the contact name
```

Comment: Gives an error with the managedQuery line.  Not really sure what to do with it.

Comment: @GrumP I had an extra 'null' in the function call. Try it again.

Comment: @GrumP managedQuery() is a member of the Activity class. That code assumes you are calling it from your Activity.

Comment: The class I am working with extends Broadcast receiver, how should I go about getting the code you posted to work?

Comment: Tried this is a class extending activity, got no compiler errors, but app crashes at run time.  Very frustrating.  Have spent a long time at it now.