# Android SDK find contact phone number by name

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to find a contacts phone number by their name. I was trying to use this tutorial but it isn't working well. I am having a hard time actually locating the name from the number part. I do not have errors. Is there an easier way to do this? Here is the tutorial I have been following. [Tutorial!](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/) I have also investigated this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0) however I am having a hard time finding a specific contact and not just all of them.

Comment: I think its already found check this [link][1]. 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079365/android-retrieve-contact-name-from-phone-number

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see that they were able to use just two lines to find the name associated with a number. How can I do the reverse?

Comment: I used this code, but how do I actually use the query results? cr.query(uri,new String[]{PhoneLookup.NUMBER}, null, null, null);