# how to import a contact name and number from csv file to android phone by programmatically

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-progressbar, contactscontract, android-file

I am new to android i am in need to read  a contact details as contact name and phone number form csv file and store it into android phone by pro grammatically please help any one .
thanks in advance

Comment: What parts of the code do you have already working? What is the problem with code that doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

It's just a read and parse CSV file program that you need .

So you can do something like :

```
 //--- If your input stream  is `inpStrm` of the csv file :

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpStrm));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] RowData = line.split(",");
             date = RowData[0];
             value = RowData[1];
            // Now use "data" and "value" as you need to 
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            inpStrm.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now `contact name` and `phone number` will be present in `data` and `value`. That's it i suppose .

Comment: the above code works to read from csv file and store into a variables.could please tell me about how to import these contacts into phone in android by programmatically .please give some idea

Comment: @user2310115 :  Look here for some ideas : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079365/android-retrieve-contact-name-from-phone-number?rq=1

Comment: In this preferred link is used  to retrieve a data from the phone .. I'm in need some idea about how to import the contacts to phone by programmatically