# How to get the name of the contact from his number

Tags: android

I am making an call reader application in which i am able to find out the number from which call is coming but now i want my application to say the name of the contact who is placing the call.I am unable to findout the name of the contact. Can anyone help.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/  this will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}
```

For more Details [Visit this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079365/android-retrieve-contact-name-from-phone-number)

Answer (score 1):

To get the name of the incoming call number,use

```
name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NAME));
```

Comment: How will i compare with the number that i have got