# Edit or insert contact intent in android

Tags: android

i have a contact number, if the contact exist in phone directory then i want to launch edit contact.

If the contact is fresh, i need to launch the edit contact screen and place the number in appropriate field.

Is there intent like this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no intent for what you intend to do so you have to do it on your own.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html) you have a brief tutorial for inserting and editing a contact using intents.

I guess the best way is looking for the contact using PhoneLookup, if there is no result, send an ACTION_INSERT intent, if there is a result, send an ACTION_EDIT.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3079443/4165582) SO question you can see how to find the contact name from a phone number using PhoneLookup. You can use it for retrieving the id and lookup_key ([PhoneLookup reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html)). But be aware that the phone number isn't unique, so you could get more than one contact.