# Error Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: java, android-sqlite

I am getting an error

> Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work

After Run project, my app stopped on this method:

```
getPriceDataByNameProductAndSupplier
```

Code:

```
/*_____________________________ My query _______________________*/
public double getPriceDataByNameProductAndSupplier(int product_id,int supplier_id)
{

Product product=null;
double  Price_for_every_one=0.0;
String query= "select max(price_for_every_one) from product_Multi_Value where _id ="+ product_id +" and _idSupplier="+ supplier_id ;
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null/*ew String[] {String.valueOf(product_id),
        String.valueOf(supplier_id)}*/); /*("product_Multi_Value",
                                     new String[] {"MAX(price_for_every_one) AS MAX"},"_id=? and _idSupplier=?",
                                     new String[] {String.valueOf(product_id),String.valueOf(supplier_id)},
                                     null,null,null)*/;// cursor.moveToFirst();
if (cursor !=null)
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        Price_for_every_one = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("price_for_every_one") );
        product = new Product(Price_for_every_one);
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
return Price_for_every_one;
}
```

Table Creation

/*_______________________ (My Table) _______________________*/
   String Crete_Table_Product_For_Multi_Value = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_Multi_Value(
                   Product_Type TEXT NOT NULL,product_date TEXT NOT NULL,supplier_date TIMESTAMP 
                   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,exp_date TEXT NOT NULL, quantity_package REAL NOT NULL, 
                   number_quantity_ber_package INTEGER NOT NULL, total_of_quantity REAL NOT NULL, 
                   price_for_Allquantity REAL NOT NULL, price_for_every_one REAL NOT NULL, 
                   price_for_sales REAL,_id INTEGER NOT NULL, idSupplier INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN 
                   KEY( _idSupplier) REFERENCES Supplier(_id), FOREIGN KEY(_id) REFERENCES 
                   product(_id));";

**Error Log**:

The error:

> E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.ans.accouting_s_p, PID: 1349
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>
> at  androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
>           at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetDouble(Native Method)
>           at android.database.CursorWindow.getDouble(CursorWindow.java:543)
>           at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getDouble(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:87)
>           at com.ans.accouting_s_p.databaseTable.DataSourceProduct.getpriceDataByNameProductAndSupplier(DataSourceProduct.java:322)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the field value with a Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903343/get-the-field-value-with-a-cursor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to access the column `price_for_every_one` in the cursor and it doesn't exist because when you use aggregation method like MAX, MIN, SUM etc
it changed the name of the column in the result unless you use `AS` keyword

in your SQL  query

```
String query = "select max(price_for_every_one) from product_Multi_Value where _id ="+ product_id +" and _idSupplier="+ supplier_id ;
```

column name in the result will be

```
max(price_for_every_one)
```

not

```
price_for_every_one
```

so you can't use the column name in

```
Price_for_every_one = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("price_for_every_one") );
```

since you are selecting only one column you can access the column by its index

```
cursor.getDouble(0)
```

or you can use `AS` keyword in your query like this

````
String query = "select max(price_for_every_one) As price_for_every_one from product_Multi_Value where _id ="+ product_id +" and _idSupplier="+ supplier_id ;```
````

I hope this helps you